# Codeigniter/CSS PDF Printout Align PDF Position

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, html-table

Problem: Currently I have problem aligning the PDF that I am creating as it is different with normal CSS that I know.

Problem:

[image]

What I need it to be solve:
Make it align, for the image I provided, I wanted "No.SAG" below "Old"

This is the code:

```html
    <table class="unstyledTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name:</th>
          <th>Test Data</th>
          <th></th>
          <th>Number card IC</th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td>Name Agent::</td>
          <td>TomHansom </td>
          <td></td>
          <td>New:</td>
          <td>foot5</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Address:</td>
          <td>werwrwrwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Old:</td>
          <td>cell5_1</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>No.SAG:</td>
          <td>cell5_2</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Number.Siri:</td>
          <td>cell5_3</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be easier to put both in columns as tables in a parent table. Check out my code below to see if this is what you were after.

```html
<table class="unstyledTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top"><table>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="unstyledTable">
            <th>Name:</th>
            <th>Test Data</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="unstyledTable">
            <td>Address:</td>
            <td>werwrwrwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="unstyledTable">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="unstyledTable">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="unstyledTable">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="unstyledTable">
            <td>Name Agent::</td>
            <td>TomHansom </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table></td>
        <td valign="top"><table>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="unstyledTable">
              <th>Number card IC</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="unstyledTable">
              <td>Old:</td>
              <td>cell5_1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="unstyledTable">
              <td>No.SAG:</td>
              <td>cell5_2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="unstyledTable">
              <td>Number.Siri:</td>
              <td>cell5_3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="unstyledTable">
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="unstyledTable">
              <td>New:</td>
              <td>foot5</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```